# How to model associative data in Apache Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-2.0, columnstore

I decided on using Cassandra for one project and after going through a lot of documentation I still cannot picture a good way of modelling associative data.

The system is supposed to store data as *types* and *instances* of those types. At the same time *types* can be related through custom *associations* which define how *instances* can be then associated.

For a more concrete example consider the following data:

- *associations*: **a1**, **a2**, **a3**
- *types*: **t1**, **t2**, **t3**
- *instances*: **t1-i1**, **t1-i2**, **t2-i3**, **t3-i4**, **t3-i5**, **t3-i6**

The user can then define how the *types* can associate:

- **t1** - **a1** - **t2**
- **t2** - **a2** - **t3**
- **t3** - **a3** - **t3**

The above will later define how the instances can associate:

- **t1-i1** - **t2-i3** (on basis of **t1** - **a1** - **t2**)
- **t2-i3** - **t3-i5** (on basis of **t2** - **a2** - **t3**)
- **t3-i5** - **t3-i6** (on basis of **t3** - **a3** - **t3**)
- **t3-i6** - **t3-i6** (on basis of **t3** - **a3** - **t3**)

Few notes on the above:

1. There can be *n* associations between 2 *types*
2. There can be an association between the same *type* / *instance* (examples above)
3. Associations between *types* define how *instances* can be associated

What would the **queries** be:

1. The system should be able to CRUD individual *associations*, *types* and *instances* of type.
2. Relations for type. (Eg: `GET /t-assoc/t1` -> [**t1**-**a1**-**t2**])
3. Relations for type of association. (Eg: `GET /t-assoc/t2/a1` -> [**t1**-**a1**-**t2**])
4. Same as above but having the complete relation
5. Relations for instance (Eg: `GET /i-assoc/t1/t1-i1` -> [<**t1**,**t1-i1**>-**a1**-<**t2**,**t2-i3**>])
6. Relations for instance of association (Eg: `GET /i-assoc/t1/t1-i1/a1` -> [<**t1**,**t1-i1**>-**a1**-<**t2**,**t2-i3**>])
7. Relations for instance of association to type (Eg: `GET /i-assoc/t1/t1-i1/a1/t3` -> [])
8. Same as above, having the complete relation
9. Similar to **3.** only that instead of returning relations, it should return the actual related types (Eg: `GET /types/t1/a1` -> [**t2**])
10. Similar to **7.**, while returning instances (Eg: `GET /instance/t1/t1-i1/a1/t2` -> [<**t2**,**t2-i3**]>)

I had some iterations on implementing the above structure, but I'm unsuccessful on representing it in a structure that will allow all the above operations to be executed in a single query. Here is the CQL version:

```
CREATE TABLE association (
  bucket_id timeuuid,
  id text,
  data map<text,text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (bucket_id, id)
);

CREATE TABLE type (
  bucket_id timeuuid,
  id text,
  data map<text,text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (bucket_id, id)
);

CREATE TABLE instance (
  bucket_id timeuuid,
  type_id text,
  id timeuuid,
  data map<text,text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((bucket_id, type_id), id)
);

CREATE TABLE type_association (
  bucket_id timeuuid,
  from_type_id text,
  association_id timeuuid,
  to_type_id text,
  reverse boolean,
  data map<text,text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (bucket_id, from_type_id, association_id, to_type_id, reverse)
);

CREATE TABLE instance_association (
  bucket_id timeuuid,
  from_type_id text,
  from_instance_id timeuuid,
  association_id timeuuid,
  to_type_id text,
  to_instance_id timeuuid,
  reverse boolean,
  data map<text,text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (bucket_id, from_type_id, from_instance_id, association_id,
    to_type_id, to_instance_id, reverse)
);
```

The reverse field was a hack to be able to discover relations from both directions. It means I would insert **t1**-**a1**-**t2** as:

1. **t1-a1-t2-true**
2. **t2-a1-t1-false**

This implementation does not favour queries no: 9 and 10. For 9 I need to perform 2 queries from which the second one is a `IN` query. This is not optimal since those will be top common queries.

Any suggestions on a different design that would allow executing the above in 1 query?

**EDIT:** As a graph structure this would be well suited for a graph database. I'm trying to solve this problem in Cassandra though.

Answer (score 1):

A graph database would be a much better solution for this problem. Basically what you try to do by yourself is creating a Vertex-Edge system.
Take a look at TitanDB from Aurelius. http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/
ThinkAurelius was recently bought by DataStax and they are currently integrating graph capabilities into the Enterprise Version of DataStax.

You can configure Titan to use cassandra as backend storage. If you want more flexibility and more functions to query the DB you can also configure it to use solr or elastic as a search engine. TitanDB is really "only" a computation engine so you can use it directly in your client. It implements the Tinkerpop3 stack, so you could change the underlying graph database to any other system implementing this stack. You would not loose the master-less scalabiliy.

Comment: I know about Titan and I agree it would make a good case for this, but I cannot accept your answer since I'm looking for a Cassandra implementation.

Comment: Thats ok :) May I ask why you don't wan't to use a graph database? Is this for learning purpose or do you really want to use this productive? Because you are really reinventing the wheel here...

Comment: It is for leaning purposes. This is advanced data modeling. I might later use Titan, but I want to make sure I leaned something here (and fully understood the arguments) before moving on.